# Proof using sum of Fourier coefficients and inner product

Tags: fourier-analysis, inner-products

[image: Problem]

I've been trying to figure this homework problem out for the last hour and can't seem to get anything going. Looking for some hints or help.

I've been trying to start using the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality and work from there.

I've also tried, for example, something like:
$\sum_{i=1}^n(\frac{x \cdot v_i}{v_i \cdot v_i})^2 \leq x \cdot x$ and then trying to use the fact that $|x \cdot v_i| \leq ||x||\cdot||v_i||$, but that still didn't yield much.

I also tried replacing $x$ in $<x,x>$ with $\sum_{i=1}^nc_iv_i$ (because $x$ is a linear combination) but still I don't know where to go from here...

What's a good starting point? Can you point me in the right direction?

EDIT: Here's what I've been trying...

I started with the Fourier Trick and worked from there:

$$c_i=x\cdot v_i$$
$$c_i \leq ||x||\cdot||v_i||$$
$$c_i \leq ||x||$$ (since the basis is orthonormal)
$$c_i^2 \leq ||x||^2$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2 \leq n||x||^2$$
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nc_i^2 \leq ||x||^2$$

It seems like I'm getting closer, but this still isn't quite the answer they're look for.

Comment: Isn't the left hand side just $x \cdot x?$

Comment: @ChrisLeary Yeah, that's right. But I'm not sure how that's supposed to help me very much.

Comment: Try Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @ChrisLeary Where and how? I listed one of the ways I tried to use it but it didn't seem to work.. What are you suggesting? Thanks

Comment: If  $u,v$ are vectors in the same inner product space, Cauchy-Schwarz says that $|u \cdot v| \leq \|u\|\|v\|,$ using dot product notation for the inner product. Now let $u=v=x.$ The absolute value is irrelevant since the left-hand side is a sum of squares.

Comment: @ChrisLeary Yeah, I've tried using that. I edited my question to include one of my attempted solutions. Where does this new solution go wrong?

Comment: Compute $<x,x>$ using the representation of $x$ as $\sum c_iv_i.$ Remember that the $v_i$ form an othonormal basis. So, $<v_i,v_j>=0$ if $i \neq j$ and $<v_i,v_i>=\|v_i\|^2=1.$ Now use Cauchy-Scwarz as recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Write $x\in V$ as an orthogonal decomposition:
$$
           x = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,c_k\rangle c_k+\left(x-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,c_k\rangle c_k\right).
$$
Conclude that
\begin{align}
    \|x\|^2 &= \left\|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,c_k\rangle c_k\right\|^2+\left\|x-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,c_k\rangle c_k\right\|^2  \\
      &\ge \left\|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle x,c_k\rangle c_k\right\|^2\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}|\langle x,c_k\rangle|^2.
\end{align}